# Why does it make difference when I use "end" or "\n" or " " (space) statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does it make difference when I use one upload only one of these three statements:

1. `print("*", end=" ")`
2. `print("* ")`
3. `print("*\n")`
   [image: Collage Pic of Outputs, because i can upload only one image]

I am getting the pyramid as shown in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/programs-printing-pyramid-patterns-python/, only when i use "end" in `print("*", end=" ")`.
The code is:

```
# Function to demonstrate printing pattern

def pypart(n):
    # outer loop to handle number of rows
    # n in this case
    for i in range(0, n):

        # inner loop to handle number of columns
        # values changing acc. to outer loop
        for j in range(0, i + 1):
            # printing stars
            print("*", end=" ")

        # ending line after each row
        print("\r")


# Driver Code
pypart(3)
```

Why does we need this line: `print("\r")`?
I didn't get it from comment above that line.

Comment: Please don't post images representing text. Post the text itself instead.

Comment: I tried that but, I lost the formatting, I meant spaces. Losing spaces will defeat the whole purpose of question.

Comment: Well, use preformatted text. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: I am new to stack overflow. I wasn't aware of all that. I'll do that from my next question. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `print("*", end=" ")` means: print a star and a space at the end
2. `print("* ")` means: print a star, a space and a newline at the end
   (default)
3. `print("*\n")` means: print a star, a newline and another
   newline at the end (default)

**More information:** [Python end parameter in `print`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gfact-50-python-end-parameter-in-print/).

Answer (score 0):

1) print("*", end=" ") means:print a star and a space at the end of the line

2) print("* ") means:print a star with a gap

3) print("*\n") means:print a star & move the cursor to the new line